# Unique IDs for Symfony select_tag() helper

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

With the select_tag() helper, is there a way to avoid passing an id to the generated  element?

If not, what do you do when you have the same form several times on a page and you want to keep ids unique?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so here's the solution:

```
select_tag($name, $option_tags, array('id'=>'label_picker_for_' . $article_id);
```